# Golang - structs, initializing and memcpy - what is the proper way?

Tags: arrays, struct, go, initialization, custom-type

I'm new to Go and I wish to translate some C/C++ code I have to Go but I haven't been able to. The problem resides in 2 places: how can I initialize a struct I've defined and how to do a "memcopy"

The code I'm talking about is this: http://play.golang.org/p/e8N255qEAk
line 69 and 74.

The C/C++ code I wanted to "translate" to Go is this:

```
            typedef char xchr;
            typedef int xint;
            typedef double xdob;
            typedef float xflt;
            typedef struct
            {
               xint p; 
               xdob lat_lon_ele[3];
               xflt psi_the_phi[3];
               xflt gear_flap_vect[3];
            }VEH1;

            avio.p = 0;
            avio.lat_lon_ele[0] = 47.460058;
            avio.lat_lon_ele[1] = -122.32104;
            avio.lat_lon_ele[2] = 8000.000;

            avio.psi_the_phi[0] = 110.5;
            avio.psi_the_phi[1] = 0.0;
            avio.psi_the_phi[2] = 0.0;

            avio.gear_flap_vect[0] = 1.0;
            avio.gear_flap_vect[1] = 0.0;
            avio.gear_flap_vect[2] = 0.0;

            VEH1* av = &avio;

            xchr data_send[6];
            data_send[0]='V';
            data_send[1]='E';
            data_send[2]='H';
            data_send[3]='1';
            data_send[4]=0;

            memcpy(&data_send[5],av,sizeof(VEH1)); // load in the data
```

The Go code looks like this:

```
            type xchr int8
            type xint int
            type xdob float64
            type xflt float32

            type VEH1 struct {
                p              xint
                lat_lon_ele    [3]xdob
                psi_the_phi    [3]xflt
                gear_flap_vect [3]xflt
            }

            type VEHA struct {
                num_p xint

                lat_lon_ele    [10][3]xdob
                psi_the_phi    [10][3]xflt
                gear_flap_vect [10][3]xflt

                lat_view, lon_view, ele_view xdob
                psi_view, the_view, phi_view xflt
            }


            var avio VEH1
            avio = &VEH1{0, {47.460058, -122.32104, 8000.000}, {110.5, 0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0, 0.0}}

            data_send := [6]xchr{'V', 'E', 'H', '1', 0, 0}
            copy(data_send[5:5], avio);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically given these basic types:

```
type xchr int8
type xint int
type xdob float64
type xflt float32
```

You want to copy the bytes (memory representation) of a value of the following `struct` type:

```
type VEH1 struct { // 52 bytes total
    p              xint    // 4 bytes (READ BELOW)
    lat_lon_ele    [3]xdob // 24 bytes
    psi_the_phi    [3]xflt // 12 bytes
    gear_flap_vect [3]xflt // 12 bytes
}
```

Note that the length of `int` in Go is platform dependent, it may be 32 bit or 64 bit depending on the target architecture you compile to. That would lead to platform dependent behavior, so let's fix it to `int32` for now:

```
type xint int32
```

This is how the byte sizes of the above `struct` is calculated. If you need `int64`, just change it and add 4 additional bytes in size calculation.

Next you want the result in an array whose element types are `xchr`. You need a big enough array, which is the "prefix" being `"VEH1"` followed by the data of the above `struct`. So it must have a size of `4+sizeof(VEH1)` which is `56`.

In Go to copy the bytes of one type to the memory space of another type, you can do it the [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) package and its general [`Pointer`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer) type. Any pointer can be cast to `unsafe.Pointer` and `unsafe.Pointer` can be cast to any pointer type, so this is your "gateway" between different pointer types.

You can take the address of a `struct` value of `VHE1`, convert it to `Pointer`, and convert the result `Pointer` to a pointer to the target data type. Dereference the pointer and now you already have the value of the other type.

The builtin [`copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) can only be used with slices, so first you need to slice your data arrays to be able to pass them to `copy()`.

You can do it like this:

```
avio := VEH1{0, [3]xdob{47.460058, -122.32104, 8000.000},
    [3]xflt{110.5, 0.0, 0.0}, [3]xflt{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", avio)

pavio := unsafe.Pointer(&avio)
pavio_arr := *((*[52]xchr)(pavio))

data_send := [56]xchr{'V', 'E', 'H', '1'}
n := copy(data_send[4:], pavio_arr[:])
fmt.Printf("Copied %d bytes\n", n)

fmt.Printf("%+v\n", data_send)
```

Output, wrapped to fit in screen:

```
{p:0 lat_lon_ele:[47.460058 -122.32104 8000] psi_the_phi:[110.5 0 0]
    gear_flap_vect:[1 0 0]}
Copied 52 bytes
[86 69 72 49 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -81 33 56 46 -29 -70 71 64 77 45 91 -21 -117
    -108 94 -64 0 0 0 0 0 64 -65 64 0 0 -35 66 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -128 63 0 0 0 0]
```

Try the working demo on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/3abTiv5QuU).

#### Having the result as `[]byte`

If you want `[]byte` result (e.g. you want to write the result to an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer)), then use `[56]byte` type for `data_send` and of course cast `pavio` to `*[52]byte`:

```
pavio := unsafe.Pointer(&avio)
pavio_arr := *((*[52]byte)(pavio))

data_send := [56]byte{'V', 'E', 'H', '1'}
n := copy(data_send[4:], pavio_arr[:])
```

Comment: Thank you icza! The only thing left for me is to write the data_send to a socket. I'm looking now for solutions on how can I pack this into a []byte

Comment: @emmerich If you change `type xchr int8` to `type xchr byte`, then you will already have a `[]byte`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't like my custom-type even if is byte

    cannot use data_send (type [57]xchr) as type []byte in argument to conn.conn.Write

Also, I've tried before this to use this:

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if err := binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, &data_send); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
    }

    _, err = conn.Write(buf.Bytes())

Also, using tcpdump I've noticed that the length differs by 4 bytes between the C++ version and the Go one: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/g0trm9mC)

Comment: @emmerich See edited answer which results in `[]byte` with minimal change.

Comment: Int *is* fixed length and the behavior *is* deterministic, *but it's platform dependent*.

Comment: @ReyCharles Yes, that's what the 2nd half of the sentence states: _"..it may be 32 bit or 64 bit depending on the target architecture you compile to. "_

Comment: Yes, that part is correct. Saying that int is not fixed-length and that the behavior is undeterministic is plain wrong, though.  I see you accepted my edit, thanks.